# How to change the sorting order in Antd's table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to change the sorting order in Antd's table. Right now, just after the component is initialized, sorting starts with "Click to sort ascending", then switches to descending and finally to none.

My goal is to change the order from ascending -> descending -> none to **descending -> ascending -> none**. Is it possible without changing tooltip messages and requests to their reverse?

I've tried using `sortDirections` and `defaultSortOrder` but they don't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the antd docs - version 4.19.4 - and `sortDirections` works in my case.

```
const CustomTable = () => {
  const tableColumns = columns.map((item) => ({ ...item }));

  return (
    <Table
      sortDirections={["descend", "ascend"]}
      columns={tableColumns}
      dataSource={data}
    />
  );
};
```

Here's a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-sorting-order-9uuv80

I didn't include the tooltip but you can see the order is *descending*, *ascending* and *none*.

Comment: It seems that I've placed the `sortDirections` in a wrong place. Everyone, watch out for that! Thank you for the support.